# Breaking early from 'CSV.foreach' enumerator

Tags: ruby, csv

I would like to validate my file.

- Should parse the file line by line (and not read the whole file into memory).
- Should exit as soon as it passes the test.
- Should consider the file valid if any of the `vendor_codes` match the provided `vendor_code`.

Some code:

```
error = "WRONG VENDOR DUMMY. This is #{account.vendor_code}"
CSV.foreach(file, options) do |row|
  if row[:vendor].to_s == account.vendor_code.to_s
    error = false
    break
  else
    next
  end
end
raise(error) if error
```

is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach is better:

```
valid = CSV.foreach(file, options).any? do |row|
  row[:vendor].to_s == account.vendor_code.to_s
end
raise("WRONG VENDOR DUMMY. This is #{account.vendor_code}") unless valid
```

Comment: Simplified the answer.

Comment: How about replacing `any? ` with `detect` ? `valid` would refer to the first correct row, or nil if there isn't one.

Comment: I guess author is interested only in the fact if file is valid, not the matching line. In this case `any?` suits better.

Comment: ...or `raise("WRONG VENDOR DUMMY. This is #{account.vendor_code}") unless CSV.foreach(file, options).any? { |row| ... }`.